# Reset providers in pacman

Tags: pacman, manjaro

I was installing linux headers with `pacman -S linux-headers` and was asked which provider I wanted.

```
[slava@mowgli Downloads]$ sudo pacman -S linux-headers
:: There are 12 providers available for linux-headers:
:: Repository core
   1) linux310-headers  2) linux312-headers  3) linux314-headers
   4) linux316-headers  5) linux318-headers  6) linux41-headers
   7) linux44-headers  8) linux46-headers  9) linux47-headers
   10) linux48-headers
```

I ended up choosing the wrong one, so I re-ran the command to change for another. I expected it to ask me which I wanted before re-installing but it did not, it skipped the the "Procceed with installation Y/n".

How can I get this choice again?

Comment: Are you sure that you're using Arch Linux and not a derivative? Please post the output of `/etc/pacman.conf`.

Comment: @sixpointzero Am actually using manjero xfce, but pretty stock. http://pastebin.com/raw/fwwbGNUz

Comment: Well, you should've used the `manjaro` tag instead of using the `arch-linux` tag.

Comment: Have you tried to remove linux-headers (`pacman -R linux-headers`) and reinstall it afterward?

Comment: @cylgalad Yes I did. One of the first things that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds odd. But perhaps try to install using the `--confirm` option.

From `man pacman`:

```
 --confirm

    Cancels the effects of a previous --noconfirm.
```

But if you didn't run the previous command with `--noconfirm` this should not have happened.

Comment: Nope, doesn't change anything.